# How to use numpy return_inverse table on a different array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a lookup table created using -

```
lookupTable, data_training_panda_y_indexed = np.unique(data_training_panda_y, return_inverse=True)
```

However, I want to apply the `lookupTable` on a different array `data_cross_validation_panda_y`

`data_training_panda_y` is a list of strings which can be these values - Incoming, Outgoing, Neutral.

So, `lookUpTable` is `ndArray ('Incoming' 'Outgoing 'Neutral')`

Code so far -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from numpy import dtype
from _codecs import lookup

#Load data
data = np.genfromtxt('../Data/bezdekIris.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=[0,1,2,3,4],dtype=None)
labels = np.genfromtxt('../Data/bezdekIris.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=[4],dtype=None)
#Shuffle the rows
np.random.shuffle(data)

#Cut the data into 3 parts
data_rows = np.size(data, 0)
training_rows = int(round(0.6*data_rows))
cross_validation_rows = int(round(0.2*data_rows))
testing_rows = data_rows - training_rows - cross_validation_rows

data_training_panda = pd.DataFrame(data[:training_rows])
data_training_panda_X = data_training_panda.iloc[:,0:4]
data_training_panda_y = data_training_panda.iloc[:,4]

data_cross_validation_panda = pd.DataFrame(data[training_rows:training_rows+cross_validation_rows])
data_cross_validation_panda_X = data_cross_validation_panda.iloc[:,0:4]
data_cross_validation_panda_y = data_cross_validation_panda.iloc[:,4]

data_testing_panda = pd.DataFrame(data[training_rows+cross_validation_rows:])
data_testing_panda_X = data_testing_panda.iloc[:,0:4]
data_testing_panda_y = data_testing_panda.iloc[:,4]

#Take out the labels from the 3 parts
lookupTable, data_training_panda_y_indexed = np.unique(data_training_panda_y, return_inverse=True)

#Label the CV and Testing 
data_cross_validation_panda_y_indexed = np.array([])
data_testing_panda_y_indexed = np.array([])
```

bezdekIris.csv Sample Data -

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Incoming
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Outgoing
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Netural
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `lookupTable`?

Comment: @klim use it on a different array.

Comment: Could you detail it? What is a typical result you want?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with code that can be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using searchsorted could be a solution.

```
data_cross_validation_panda_y_indexed = np.searchsorted(lookupTable, data_cross_validation_panda_y)
```